# Number of Patterns in Cutting Stock Problem Grows Exponentially

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

Consider the cutting stock problem where $L$ is the length of the stock and $n$ is the total number of patterns.  If customer demands are any length between $1, 2, \ldots, L$, why is it the case that $n \geq 2^{\sqrt{L}-1}$?

Comment: I think you are asking about the number of *partitions* of $L$. Using that as a search term, you should have some luck finding an answer to your question.

Comment: https://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/d10/d10.pdf gives a proof that the number of partitions of $L$ is at least $(1/14)e^{2\sqrt L}$, but I think your question is given a much simpler answer in the statement of the question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184296/lower-bounds-for-the-partition-function By the way, $2^{\sqrt L}$ is *not* considered to be exponential growth, on account of that square root in the exponent.

Comment: Have you had a look at those links?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has lost interest.